# can I set the limit to avoid disk full

Tags: druid

Is there any way that I can set the limit on historical node? getting error message that says "disk full" frequently, can I fix this?

Druid version I am using is 0.18.1
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

druid doesn't have resource quotas yet (disk, cpu, etc).  Maybe in the future.  You'd need to monitor disk usage over time in some way.

Answer (score 0):

In the historical runtime properties we set the "freeSpacePercent" argument to leave operational room for the historical processes. In our experience this is the only thing that is honored.

Other historical runtime properties like maxSize and druid.server.maxSize are only used as guidance.

```
druid.segmentCache.locations=[{"path":"/mnt/druid/segment-cache","maxSize":400000000000, "freeSpacePercent": 5.0}]
```